# Why does upsampling and interpolation by convolution introduce a shift compared to imresize?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, interpolation, upsampling

For purposes of understanding the process - not for any practical purpose for which I could use imresize - I wanted to show that 2x upsampling followed by convolution with an appropriate kernel (presumably the 2d equivalent of a "triangle") is equivalent to `imresize(x,scalingFactor,'bilinear')`, However I cannot do it perfectly. It "almost" works in the sense that qualitatively it looks very similar but it is as if it is slightly "shifted" cf. code below. Moreover for upsampling higher than ×2 I don't know how to build the correct kernel. I tried below, with zero "stuffing" but that is not correct. Any  help and explanations/corrections are greatly appreciated.

```
N = 64;
%x = phantom(N)+0.25;
x = imresize(im2double(imread('cameraman.tif')),[N N]);
s = 2;

x_matlab_bilinear = imresize(x,s,'bilinear');

kernel1D = [0.5, 0.5*ones(1,s-2), 1, 0.5*ones(1,s-2), 0.5];
bilinearKernel =  kernel1D.'*kernel1D;

x_up = zeros(s*N,s*N);
x_up(1:s:end,1:s:end) = x;
x_custom_bilinear = conv2(x_up, bilinearKernel,'same');

figure;
imagesc(bilinearKernel);

figure;
subplot(141);
imagesc(x_up);colormap('gray');
subplot(142);
imagesc(x_matlab_bilinear);colormap('gray');title('x up matlab bilinear');
subplot(143);
imagesc(x_custom_bilinear);colormap('gray');title('x up custom bilinear');
subplot(144);
imagesc(x_matlab_bilinear-x_custom_bilinear);colorbar;title('diff');
```

[image]

For e.g. x8 upsampling I would use the following kernel (generated by my formula):

[image]

above is my kernel for interpolating a 2 times upsampled image.

For the delta-impulse image the results of 2 times upsampling are the following for the same above code but just replacing the first lines by

```
N=6; x=zeros(N); x(3,3)=1;
```

:

[image]

Comment: For 2x resampling, the only difference is that MATLAB uses a different output coordinate system, its output is effectively shifted by half a pixel compared to yours. I recommend that you experiment with a small delta-pulse image, which shows you perfectly what a linear process does.

Comment: For other scales, you also need to fix your kernel: it should be a triangle!

Comment: Try this test image: `N=6; x=zeros(N); x(3,3)=1;`.

Comment: ok will post the result with this delta pulse image, thanks alot. Also I posted the 8 times upsampling kernel I would use (just for the sake of example) is that correct?

Comment: No, it needs to be a triangle, so that when you’re closer to one sample than the other, you weigh that sample more than the other.

Comment: hum i don't really see how you build it, mine is like a triangle with just "edges" - sort of ?

Comment: and for your impulse, when I look at it I have the impression that my kernel aligns well with it and that Matlab does something else ... I dont understand this "other system of coordinates" that Matlab uses you say? It seems very confusing and what is the point?

Comment: MATLAB shifts by half a pixel, so two new samples on one line are at the same distance of the input pixel. For the kernel, see https://www.google.com/search?q=linear+interpolation+kernel&client=safari&hl=en-us&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRzNmf2O72AhW5JjQIHTy1Dt4Q_AUoAXoECAIQAQ&biw=375&bih=631&dpr=3 — so for  s=3 it would be `[1/3, 2/3, 1, 2/3, 1/3]`.

Comment: ok thanks, I appreciate you took time for this. Yet it seems "crazy" to complicate things with "half-pixel" shifts no?

Comment: for your triangle now i see: [1/3, 2/3, 1, 2/3, 1/3]'*[1/3, 2/3, 1, 2/3, 1/3] plotted in 3D with surf looks like a little "tent" indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear interpolation kernel should be a triangle. You can construct it like this:

```
kernel1D = [(1:s)/s, (s-1:-1:1)/s];
```

The difference between MATLAB's `imresize` and your method for `s=2` is a half-pixel shift. This is equivalent to shifting the kernel by half a pixel. So instead of a kernel `[1/2, 1, 1/2]`, you'd use a kernel `[1/4,3/4,3/4,1/4]`. I was able to reproduce MATLAB's result like this (up to differences at the boundary, where MATLAB pads the input by repeating values, rather than adding zeros like `conv2` does):

```
kernel1D = [1/4,3/4,3/4,1/4];  % kernel shifted by half a pixel!
bilinearKernel =  kernel1D.'*kernel1D;

x_up = zeros(s*N,s*N);
x_up(2:s:end,2:s:end) = x;   % note the shift here!
x_custom_bilinear = conv2(x_up, bilinearKernel,'same');
```

I'm guessing that the half-pixel shift makes the operation more symmetric: note that in your original result, you have a black column of pixels on the right. Shift by half a pixel, and now both the left and right columns of pixels contain the same fraction of "invented" (extrapolated) data.

Comment: very interesting thanks, but I wonder why is it not rather >> imtranslate([0.5 1 0.5],[0.5 0])

ans =

    0.2500    0.7500    0.7500
for the 0.5 pixel shift rahter than 4 values you get [1/4,3/4,3/4,1/4]?

Comment: I hope I am not abusing of your kindness but maybe you will be interested to look at my other main question about this topic, a even more challenging one : https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82295/how-to-implement-interpolation-by-convolution-for-rotation-of-an-image-by-an-non

Comment: @SheppLogan: It is the continuous-domain triangle that you translate, and then apply point-sampling. So there are 4 samples that hit the triangle, not 3. You only get 3 if the origin of the triangle hits a sample.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the explanation, you are a very knowledgeable person!