# How to implement interpolation by convolution for rotation of an image by an angle which is not a multiple of 90 degrees?

Tags: interpolation, geometry

I know that the usual way to perform rotation of an image is to compute the new pixel coordinates by multiplying with a rotation matrix $ \begin{pmatrix}x_{rot} \\ y_{rot} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} cos(a) & -sin(a)\\  sin(a) & cos(a)\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ and then, lets say for example for bilinear interpolation, to take the weighted average of the 4 closest pixel intensites  (a neighborhood of pixels values located around $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$) in the original image (looking "backwards"). Of course here the coordinates x,y, of the pixels are treated distinctly from the intensities at these x,y locations used to perform the weighted averages (i.e., it doesn't make sense to multiply pixel intensities by the rotation matrix nor does it make sense to average pixel coordinates, these are 2 distinct steps). (I put for angles "not a multiple of 90 degrees" since these obviously do not require interpolation).

My question is that I would be interested in a practical implementation (e.g. Matlab or python) of performing ***interpolation by convolution with an interpolation kernel***, much like for image up-sampling (like in here: [Why does upsampling and interpolation by convolution introduce a shift compared to imresize?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82292/why-does-upsampling-and-interpolation-by-convolution-introduce-a-shift-compared)), ***but*** for the case of ***rotations***. I've heard/read that this could be done by some kind of matrix multiplication with a matrix filled with the convolution kernel arranged in some (at the moment mysterious way!) for me. I have absolutely *no idea* and wasn't able to find elsewhere how to do that but I know it can be very useful in some situations. Any ideas? If you have a mathematical formulation going along with the implementation this is very interesting also.

Comment: You cannot do this with a convolution, because at each output pixel you need a different transformation. You can do it with a matrix multiplication (where the image is converted into a vector of length N, and the magic matrix is NxN), but that would be terribly inefficient. The better way to rotate is to apply 3 shearings in sequence. See for example here: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~fricke/projects/israel/paeth/rotation_by_shearing.html

Comment: oh very interesting ok, yet if you have time and if you don't mind - even if inefficient i d be interested if you can explain how to build this "magic" matrix. I was sure you had the answer !

Comment: I've never done it, it would take a bit of puzzling, I don't think I have time to figure it all out today. The process involves finding the 4 input pixels closest to the rotated location for each output pixel, and setting those values in the large matrix to the right weights to get linear interpolation.

Comment: ok sure I understand. If ever you have time i 'd be interested, and i will try on my side as well. The reason is that it might be interesting for some kind of optimization problem where everything is formulated in matrix form